# Delete part of dynamic array

Tags: c++

I created an array with the maximum dimension for text input. Now, I want to remove the remaining unnecessary part in order to free the memory. I am not allowed to use `std::string`, I need to use `char[]` arrays only.

Also, if you know better way how to use only char and allocate dynamic memory for text input, please help me.
I do not know how many characters the user will enter

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *text = new char[256];
    cout << "Input text: ";
    cin.getline(text,256,'\n');
    while (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max, '\n');
        cout << "Input text: ";
        cin.getline(text,256,'\n'); //need to delete part after '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you change the tag to `C`?

Comment: You can't do that – you need to copy to another, smaller, array. It's not very clear what you think you need to delete or why, though.

Comment: because i need to use only char. String type not allowed.

Comment: Use a temporary dynamic array.

Comment: @DenAndreychuk It is correct to tag this as C++, since that's what it is. However, you should have posted the artificial homework requirements as part of the question. Hang on, I'll edit it.

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Is it also a requirement to "save" the bytes? Otherwise, a normal PC has billions of bytes, so saving 200 doesn't seem to be that important. And if you do more work, the program will be larger which reduces the "savings".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a temporary dynamic array then copy the part you wanted from the original array then delete the original array then assign the original pointer to the temporary pointer:

```
char* szTxt = new char[256];
std::cin.getline(szTxt, 256, '\n');
std::cout << szTxt << std::endl;

const int size = strlen(szTxt);
char* szTmp = new char[size + 1];
strncpy(szTmp, szTxt, size);

szTmp[size] = '\0';

delete[] szTxt;
szTxt = szTmp;

std::cout << szTxt << std::endl;
std::cout << "Size: " << size << std::endl;

delete[] szTxt;
```

Comment: Your code will fail at `szTmp[5] = '\0'`. Increase the size by 1 at the `new` statement.

Comment: @iBug: Thanx! I didn't notice that. Edited.

Answer (score 5):

Just use std::string instead of a C array of char.  It will be sized automatically according to the input length.

Use the free function `std::getline()` instead of `istream::getline()`:

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: Ye, I know. But in my homework i must use only char. String type not allowed.

Comment: If you write a question and tag it C++ you have to expect people with use C++ strings to answer it.  You never said that wasn't allowed.  I'm going to leave this answer here, as it addresses the question as written.

Comment: Corrected. Sorry, this my first topic.